# Remove last comma before "]" in a json file using python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create a json file in below format. However, I'm unable to remove the last comma just before "]"

```
fl = open('fri.txt', 'r')
fw = open('test.txt', 'w')

lines=fl.readlines()
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
#print(lines)
#print(type(lines))
month = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']
fw.write(str.upper('"%3s": [ \n' % month[11]))
for row in lines:        
    if row.find("-12-") != -1:
         #fw.write('string exists in file')
         #fw.write('line Number:', lines.index(row))
        fw.write(str(' "%2s",' % lines[lines.index(row)][-2:] + "\n"))
fw.write("],\n")
fl.close
```

Output: test.txt

```
"DEC": [ 
 "06",
 "13",
 "20",
 "27",
],
```

Expected output:

```
"DEC": [ 
 "06",
 "13",
 "20",
 "27"
],
```

I need to remove the last comma '"27",' here. I tried to use \b.But, its not working. Kindly assist to achieve this in a better way. Similar blocks will be created for other months too. So, It has to be done in each of those blocks.

tried using backspace character. But, its not working.

Comment: Try replacing `fw.write(str(' "%2s",' % lines[lines.index(row)][-2:] + "\n"))` with  `fw.write(', '.join(f'"{row[-2:]}"') + '\n')` ; btw, unless I'm sorely confused, `lst[lst.index(item)]` = `item` ...

Comment: Why aren't you using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to write JSON?

Comment: "Similar blocks will be created for other months too." Why, can't you use a loop over `m` with `% month[m]` and `row.find("-%s-" % (m+1))`?

Comment: Thank you both tobias_k and dominikfey . Both the solutions are working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with strings, using backspace `(\b)` won't work because it only moves the cursor back without actually removing characters from the string.

You can achieve this by using `str.join()` method to join the list items with commas and it prevents the unwanted comma from appearing.

Here is the adjusted code:

```
fl = open('fri.txt', 'r')
fw = open('test.txt', 'w')

lines = fl.readlines()
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]

month = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']

fw.write(str.upper('"%3s": [ \n' % month[11]))

items = []
for row in lines:
    if row.find("-12-") != -1:
        items.append('"%2s"' % lines[lines.index(row)][-2:])

fw.write(",\n".join(items) + "\n")
fw.write("],\n")

fl.close()
fw.close()
```

Now the Output looks like this:

```
"DEC": [ 
"06", 
"13", 
"20", 
"27"
],
```

Greetings DF

Comment: This produces invalid json output, because there's still a trailing comma *after* the array. In general, it's a *very* bad idea to try to cobble together json in this way. The correct approach is build a proper `dict` and then convert it to the right format using the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: @dominikfey - Thank you very much for the updated code and also valuable suggestion to follow the right approach while coding. The output should work for my requirement. However, can we add a new line after comma so that the dates come up in different lines?

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya Yes, you can easily do this by adding a `\n` to the first fw.write line. So the result would be `fw.write(",\n".join(items) + "\n")` . But I have edited the code in my reply to apply this.

Comment: @dominikfey - Perfect now. But the previous output was also fine. Thank you very much for quick resolution :). But, it looks like same issue which i mentioned in other comment. The main code is not working after merging this. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @dominikfey - All good now. I was triggering the new piece of code from a wrong position. Thank you one again.

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya Glad to hear it's working. If it doesn't, feel free to contact me again.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are not *really* using JSON but just something similar, I would *strongly* suggest using the builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. Also, you mentioned that you'd repeat that block for the other months, but you can just use a loop for that. I am not sure how exactly your input looks, but I'd suggest trying something like this:

```
import json

months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']    
with open('fri.txt', 'r') as fl:
    res = {m: [] for m in months}
    for line in fl:
        for i, m in enumerate(months, start=1):
            if f"-{i:02}-" in line:
                res[m].append(line.strip()[-2:])

with open('test.txt', 'w') as fw:
    json.dump(res, fw, indent=2)
```

(Minor changes: iterating the lines without storing them all in a list, using `in` instead of `find`, using `with` to open and close files, and not needlessly using `index`.)

Alternatively, you may also store the lines in a list and then use a nested dict- and list-comprehension, which *may* or may not be considered more readable:

```
with open('fri.txt', 'r') as fl:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fl]
    res = {
        m: [line[-2:] for line in lines if f"-{i:02}-" in line]
        for i, m in enumerate(months, start=1)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this new approach. The out format looks fine. However, the code is returning dates only from Oct to Dec.  Rest of them just display as "SEP": [], with no values.

Comment: I know your answer is only a suggestion (since the input format is unclear), but I wonder whether the month numbers are zero-padded (i.e. like the day numbers)? Perhaps it would be more robust to use a regexp to find matching lines, and then convert the result to an `int` for use as a list index (which would also be more efficient than checking every month per line). Something like: `if match := re.search('-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-', line): res[months[int(match.group(1)) - 1]].append(line.strip()[-2:])`.

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya In this case, as ekhumoro suggested, the months values are probably zero padded, i.e. my code looks for `-9-` when it should be `-09-`. Please try again now.

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya It would be helpful if you edited your question and showed a sample linput file.

Comment: @tobias_k - Fantastic. Perfectly working now :). Thank you very much for the quick solution.

Comment: @ekhumoro - The updated code is working as expected now. The input is a text file with the list of dates in format "%Y-%m-%d"

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya The input file does not happen to be CSV? In this case, best use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read it, or `-12-` might be found in other contexts than the date, too. But that's a different question, glad it worked now.

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya So what about the years, then? Do you really want all the days from different years added to the list for the same month? What about duplicates? I very much suspect there's a much better way to handle the input file than your question currently suggests.

Comment: @tobias_k - But facing one issue. When I tried to merge this piece of code with the main code where the input file is getting generated, its not working. no values within square brackets {
  "JAN": [],
  "FEB": [],
  "MAR": [],
  "APR": [],
  "MAY": [],
  "JUN": [],
  "JUL": [],
  "AUG": [],
  "SEP": [],
  "OCT": [],
  "NOV": [],
  "DEC": []
}

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya The first version of my code just iterates the lines in the file, without storing them in a list (the second version does that). This means that if there are other parts of the code reading the file (and e.g. storing them in a list, as in your original code), then the file will already be depleted and the loop has nothing left to iterate over.

Comment: No problem @tobias_k. I'm checking how its working separately and not in my original code. The main code is just creating  fri.txt file.

Comment: @tobias_k and ekhumoro - All good now. I was triggering the new piece of code from a wrong position. Thank you one again.

Comment: @tobias_k - one last question. Is there any way to discard the first "{" as I have couple of lines to print which I will handle it separately like print { line1 \n line2. Or, can you let me know how to insert those lines after your code prints the 1st "{"

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya You can `json.dumps` to a string, then remove the first char and merge with your custom header before writing to file.

Comment: @tobias_k - Thank you. I haven't used the json module before. Would you be able to help to provide the updated code snippet ?

Comment: @Siddarthkaundinya Sorry, but no. Please read the linked docs, and if that does not help post a new, complete question, with more context. Feel free to ping me then.